# Is a signficiant interaction term in Poisson really statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, poisson-regression

I am very aware that the

> magnitude of the interaction effect in nonlinear models does not equal the marginal effect of the interaction term, can be of opposite sign, and its statistical significance is not calculated by standard software." (Ai & Norton, 2003) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176503000326

While I know that Ai & Norton are looking at Probit/Logit regressions, I am worried that their concerns might also apply to other models with non-linear dependent variable.

I fit the following poisson regression:

```
poisson_1 <- glm(death ~ team + product + team:product + offset(log(exposure)), data=clean, family=poisson)
```

where death measures whether a startup dies, team refers to the quality of the founding team, product is a measure for the startup's product and team:product is the interaction term. Exposure measures the exposure time.

Plotting the marginal effects of the interaction is not problematic. What I am interested in, **is** whether **the reported statstical signficance** is **reliable**.

```
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -8.24636    0.10611 -77.715  < 2e-16 ***
team                 -0.70149    0.09528  -7.362 1.81e-13 ***
product              -0.51265    0.10356  -4.950 7.41e-07 ***
team:product         -0.23632    0.07181  -3.291 0.000999 ***
```

Should I be concerned about the statistical significance of Team:Product, as the above quote from Ai and Norton leads me to believe?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The coefficient of the interaction is reliable.  That quote you mention talks about the marginal effect, which is like (not really, but sort of) an average over the team and product.  They are fundamentally different concepts.  If you would like an estimate of the marginal effect, I would recommend taking a look at `emmeans` in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Poisson model, the expected value is

$$E[y \vert x,z,e]=\exp(\alpha + \beta x + \gamma x \cdot z + \ln e).$$

The derivative of that is
$$\frac{\partial E[y \vert x,z,e]}{\partial x}=\exp(\alpha + \beta x + \gamma x \cdot z + \ln e )\cdot(\beta+\gamma z).$$

There are at least a couple of ways to proceed from here. One option is to note that the first term on the RHS is positive since it's just the predicted count, so we can divide through by it:

$$\frac{\partial E[y \vert x,z,e]}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{1}{E[Y \vert x,z,e]}=\beta+\gamma z.$$

Note that the LHS is now a semi-elasticity, so $\beta+\gamma z$ is the percent change in expected $y$ associated with a 1 unit change in $x$. Some people find it useful to multiply by a 100 here.

Plugging your coefficients into it, we get something like $$\epsilon=\beta+\gamma z = -0.51265 - 0.23632 \cdot z.$$

Now we can ask, how does that semi-elasticity change with $z$? To answer that, we can differentiate it with respect to $z$ and get $-0.23632$. The interaction coefficient and its statistical significance are indeed "reliable" here and tell us that the semi-elasticity is becoming more negative as $z$ increases.

Comment: Thanks so much Dimitriy. This was exactly the type of answer that I was looking for. Very helpful, comprehensive, and to the point.

Comment: @Odysseus Please select this as the answer using the checkmark on the left.

Comment: sorry, forgot that. Just checked the checkmark :)